# How to activate the microphone in Win 10 only when a certain key is pressed?

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

As a quite frequent user of the microphone in Windows 10, especially using TeamSpeak (with Push-to-Talk), I feel worried knowing my (propably not bullet-proof) system can listen to my terrible singing, even when I'm not pressing a button. *Call me old fashioned, but...*

Is it somehow possible to **keep the microphone deactivated until a certain key is pressed?** So even malware woudn't be able to access the input as easly as it could do right now?

Comment: For teamspeak-only, you can set a key (e.g. capslock) that toggles whether microphone is disabled and you can keep fingering that key like I do.  There are also some scripting languages out there (maybe [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)) that can do what you want.

Comment: Thanks ecube, thats what I'm doing right now, insted I wanted to have the mic muted within my whole system. I've found [MicMute](https://code.google.com/archive/p/micmute/downloads) (open source) which works on Win 10 and allows to create a keyboard shortcut. Seems to be working great so far.